# Create map of matching elements in two lists

Tags: java, lambda, collections, java-8, java-stream

I have two lists. I want to create a map which will have *true* for the matching element and *false* for the unique one in java 8.

*Eg*.

**Input**-

> List 1 = [A,B,C,D] 
>   List 2 = [B,C,Y,Z]

**Output**-

> ***Map***:
>
> A,false
>
> B,true
>
> C,true
>
> D,false

My code:

```
Map<String,Boolean> map = new HashMap<>();
            for(String var1 : list1) {
                boolean value;
                if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(list2)) {
                    Optional<String> valueOptional = list2.stream()
                            .filter(e1 -> e1.equalsIgnoreCase(var1))
                            .findAny();
                    value = valueOptional.isPresent();
                    map.put(var1, value);
                }
            }
```

Comment: I saw you also suffered with Hybris. Still, please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Finally please read this [question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, create a `Set` using the second list. Then use the `toMap` collector to create the map which has the string as it's key, and it's existence in the setTwo as the value. Here's how it looks.

```
Set<String> setTwo = new HashSet<>(listTwo);
Map<String, Boolean> existenceMap = listOne.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s, setTwo::contains, (a, b) -> a));
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend map with boolean key and values as list

```
Map<Boolean, List<String>> map = list1.stream()
                                      .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(list2::contains));   // or set::contains
```